# Asymptotic bound of the series $\sum_{n\leq x}\log n / \varphi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Could someone give me a hint on the computation of the asymptotic bound for the following series
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\log n }{ \varphi(n)}\,,
$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler totient function? Also a bibliography suggestion would be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\underset{n\leq x}{\sum}\frac{1}{\varphi\left(n\right)}=C\left(\log\left(x\right)+O\left(1\right)\right)$$
 where $C=\frac{315\zeta\left(3\right)}{2\pi^{4}}$
 . Now use Abel summation formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula.

Comment: Nice job Marco! Thanks!

Comment: @GIANCANE You're welcome ;)